# Should exogenous variables be time-shifted in ARIMA forecasts? And is correlation a good predicator?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I’m forecasting many commodity price series.  One, for example, is a commodity priced in Norwegian krone and so I am adding the NKR/USD exchange rate as an exogenous variables.  However, there is likely to a delay between the exchange rate changing and this being reflected in the commodity price.

Linear models, I would first find the best correlation between the predictor series and the series of variable, and use that in the model, e.g. lm(commodity ~ lag/lead(demand) + lag/lead(trade flows).  I would expect the same is true for ARIMA models, to ensure the exogenous series are contemporaneous,  with series being modelled.

1) When adding exogenous variables to ARIMA models, e.g. auto.arima(commodity, xreg = "NKR/USD"), is it advantageous to lag/lead the exogenous variables?

2) If the answer to 1 is, ‘Yes, it is better to lag/lead’, then will the optimum time-shift be when they are most strongly correlated?  Or is another test better for selecting the shift?

A test would be better than producing many time-shifted models and comparing them.

There is not (yet) any coding to show, but it will follow based on the answer.

Thank you for any insights,

TC

Comment: I would guess there would be very little delay since any delay would mean arbitrage opportunities and that would be acted on in split seconds (through algorithmic trades). However, this makes your question even more interesting as you can test if this hypothesis is correct.

Comment: In this case the prices of the commodities change monthly or even quarterly, and so there is little opportunity for arbitrage.  Apart from exchange rates, I'm also including exogenous variable would be trade flows, such as exports.

Comment: How are you handling the fact that you don't have future values for the "exogenous" variables? Are you also forecasting those? Why not use a multivariate model? The answer to 2 is no: the best model is the one with the best out-of-sample performance, not in-sample correlation.

Comment: When it comes to produce the forecasts, I'm thinking I will use either an external forecast of the exogenous variables, e.g. IMF, or use statistical forecasts of the exogenous variables, e.g. ARIMA model of the exogenous variables. On your second comment, would it not hold that, "correlation out-of-sample would be the same as in sample"?  Statistically speaking.  Thank you.

Comment: If you use a multivariate model like VAR, or if you use ARIMA for the exogenous variables, you are already potentially explicitly or implicitly including lagged versions of the exogenous variables anyway, so obviously yes, including those can be useful. Including "leads" is less likely to work meaningfully. And no, those are not the same at all because it would require your model to be exactly correct (which is never the case, it's just an approximation) and your parameters to be known. In-sample measures are of essentially no value, you must test forecasting models out-of-sample.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I'm most interested in your point, 'including "leads" is less likely to work meaningfully',  By "leading", I think of an using an indicator, as an exogenous variable, that changes in advance of the series I'm interested in.  For example, higher investment will bring higher production and lower prices (very simplified, I know). So, I'd imagine leading exogenous variables would be as useful as lagged variables.  I'll produce some models and see how the accuracy changes.

Comment: I think we're ultimately saying the same thing here but I would call that a "lag" of the exogenous variable, not a "lead", i.e. you have Y_t = f(X_{t-h}), h > 0, which is fine. I'm saying that the opposite situation will not work, where Y_t = f(X_{t+h}), a function of a future value of the exogenous variable.